# Scope is null after constructor

Tags: angularjs, typescript

Pretty new at typescript and angular. I'm trying to get a modal dialog to close through the close() method. However, when I call the close method the scope is null for some reason.

This is the controller for the dialog:

```
module Controllers
{
export interface IDetailsScope extends ng.ui.bootstrap.IModalServiceInstance
{
    Title: string;        

    CloseModal();
}

export class DetailsController
{
    static $inject = ['$scope'];  

    Scope: IDetailsScope;  

    constructor($scope: IDetailsScope)
    {                           
        this.Scope = $scope;

        this.Scope.Title = "Hello World";  
        this.Scope.CloseModal = this.CloseModal;          
    }

    CloseModal()
    {            
        this.Scope.close();
    }
}
}
```

The title property comes through to the modal dialog and the CloseModal method is called, but the scope is undefined so this call fails:

```
this.Scope.close();
```

This is how the modal is being shown:

```
this.ModalInstance = this.ModalService.open(
            {
                templateUrl: 'App/Views/Details/Details.html',
                controller: Controllers.DetailsController,
            });
```

Thanks

Comment: Fire up a debugger and see what "scope" you are inside CloseModal(). this() might not refer to the "class context" on this instance

Comment: Hmmm... Not too sure how to determine whether its in the right scope, but after inspecting the this() object when inside the CloseModal method, only it's parent object contains a Title property that matches up to the Title property defined in the class, not sure if that means anything.

Comment: what if you call close()/this.close() in CloseModal(), instead of this.Scope.close() or Scope.close()

Comment: Nope, this.close() isnt a method in DetailsController and close() tries to close the browser window.

Comment: Prefer to use controller as the vm as documented here : http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WdtVn_8K17E&hd=1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given your code, ensure you are calling

```
CloseModal()
```

From your HTML. Since that is want you exposed on the scope.

Also try using a lambda to capture the context of 'this' when passing functions around in the controller definition. i.e.

```
CloseModal = ()=> {
```

Finally I recommend not modifying the scope and using your class as the VM as documented here : http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WdtVn_8K17E&hd=1 which has additional advantages when it comes to scope inheritance.

Comment: Oh sweet, yeah I removed the interface and set $scope.vm = this and it worked like a charm, thanks man!